# How to rebuild apk after modifying/instrumenting its bytecode?

Tags: android, build, apk

I need to instrument the dalvik bytecode of any given .apk file as part of my research and to obtain working, modified .apk with the instrumented bytecode.

I am programming in Java 1.6 under Windows 7.

**Input**

- The original .apk file with the original, unchanged `classes.dex` dalvik bytecode.
- the instrumented `classes.dex` bytecode of the .apk (yes, we assume we already instrumented the bytecode).

**Desired output**

- The .apk file with the instrumented `classes.dex` bytecode instead of the original.

**Problem statement**

What is the most straightforward way to obtain the desired output from Java source code?

Comment: you write this question to just write your answer?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem [yes, here is why :)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update Apr 12 '16

Regarding step 2 of original answer:

The sources of current version of `ApkBuilder` can be found [in the official repo here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-6.0.1_r31/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/build/ApkBuilder.java) and comment explaining why it should be used can be found [also in the official repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-6.0.1_r31/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/build/ApkBuilderMain.java#181).

In your local Android SDK installation, the classes seem to live in `android-sdk/tools/lib/sdklib.jar`

---

## Original answer Nov 30 '12

### Step 1: remove the original classes.dex

To rebuild the .apk with custom `classes.dex` file first we need to delete the original `classes.dex` file from it. This can be easily done using the the `aapt.exe` tool from [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) install dir, e.g. located here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe`

The command:

```
aapt.exe remove <path-to-the-apk> classes.dex
```

will remove the file.

### Step 2: rebuild the .apk

There is a lot of confusion about building .apks as the `(...)\android-sdk\tools\apkbuilder.bat` script is deprecated. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/sls2uFYWuWE) for details.

Behind the scenes the script calls `ApkBuilderMain` which calls non-deprecated `ApkBuilder`.

Based on no longer available unofficial sources, I came up with the following code snippet:

```java
  /**
   * Builds the {@code sourceApk} with bytecode merged from {@code classesDex}. The built .apk file has the same
   * name as {@code sourceApk} and is put in {@code outputDir}.<br/>
   * <br/>
   * <b>Precondition:</b> The {@code sourceApk} doesn't contain {@code classes.dex}, so the {@code classesDex} can be
   * merged into it.
   */  
  private static File buildApk(File sourceApk, File classesDex, File outputDir) throws Exception
  {

    File outputApk;
    try {
      outputApk = new File(outputDir, sourceApk.getName());
      ApkBuilder builder = new ApkBuilder(outputApk, sourceApk, classesDex, ApkBuilder.getDebugKeystore(), null);
      builder.sealApk();
    } catch (ApkCreationException e) {
      throw new Exception(e);
    } catch (SealedApkException e) {
      throw new Exception(e);
    }

    return outputApk;
  }
```

Comment: `Sources` link is broken. Also it would be cool if you created GitHub project with all dependencies included.

Comment: @mixel I updated my answer. I won't have time to make a GitHub project out of it, sorry!